# Salesforce API authentication

Tags: authentication, salesforce, restful-authentication

I'd like to use the search API of salesforce. Is it possible to authenticate without a username/password, e.g. with some kind of permanent authentication token?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OAuth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) to get an access and refresh token.  But you'll have to make sure you handle token expiration stuff.

Comment: Thanks so far. I can request the authentication token without username/password?

Comment: We have an internal "Google" where we can search different platforms (Atlassian products like Jira, Confluence, but also Slack and a few other tools). Now sales saw that and wants salesforce to be searchable by that tool, too. So the idea was to use this salesforce REST Api: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm . But since a server executes the request it needs to authenticate without username/password. Something like an Api key. Do you have an idea how to do that? I don't have salesforce access so I can't try it out.

Comment: You can either do the OAuth flow where a user grants an app access via a web UI or you can provide the integration user's credentials to the app.  Those are the only options I'm aware of for your use case.